# How to activate functions on .org files from within agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, sorting

From agenda view, is it possible to execute functions on specific .org files?

*Example setup: `foo.org` and `bar.org` are source files for agenda*

*Example working function from :* [Sort entire hierarchy in an Org mode buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43748/sort-entire-hierarchy-in-an-org-mode-buffer)

```
(defun sort-all-org-entries ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((fun #'(lambda nil
                 (condition-case nil
                     (org-sort-entries nil ?d)
                   (user-error t)))))
    (org-map-entries fun)))
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 
    (lambda()
        (local-set-key (kbd "g") 'sort-all-org-entries)))
```

The example function `sort-all-org-entries` works correctly if `M-x sort-all-org-entries` is activated in the buffer for either foo.org or bar.org.

However, when `g` is pressed in the agenda buffer, the function is presumably executed only in the agenda as it presumably does not have a target .org file.

**edit**

Is there a way to define `g` to execute `sort-all-org-entries` at the beginning of `foo.org`, even though `g` is activated from the agenda buffer?

Comment: You are not asking anything different than what you asked in your [other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68552/org-mode-sort-specific-tree-and-refresh-agenda/68559?noredirect=1#comment109617_68559) and so the answer remains the same: even if you can determine that the entry in the agenda came from `foo.org` (which I'm sure you can), you also need to somehow tell it *WHERE* in that buffer to execute the function. You have added nothing here to specify that crucial piece of information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Org Mode: Sort specific tree and refresh agenda](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68552/org-mode-sort-specific-tree-and-refresh-agenda)

Comment: The other question was location dependent for activation of the function, as the result would change depending on pointer location within the buffer relative.  This question is an attempt to be more generic with functions that execute similarly regardless of pointer position.  For simplicity, I edited to execute at the beginning of the buffer if location is specified.

Comment: It's still location dependent if I judge from your answer: your answer does not necessarily execute the function at the beginning of the buffer. Instead, it depends on the position you were at, before switching to the agenda to call the function.

Comment: Based on testing, the sorting code appears to sort a tree correctly, whether point was at the beginning of the buffer before the tree or at the end of the buffer, after the sort tree.

Comment: That's correct. I missed the fact that you are calling `org-map-entries` without a matcher, which makes it apply the function to every headline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: New solution based on comment recommendations**

`with-current-buffer` is a useful command for temporarily working within a buffer. This can be used to execute the function without leaving the agenda buffer.

```
(defun sort-all-org-entries ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer "foo.org" 
    (let ((fun #'(lambda nil
                 (condition-case nil
                     (org-sort-entries nil ?d)
                   (user-error t)))))
    (org-map-entries fun)) 
  (org-agenda-redo())) 
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 
    (lambda()
        (local-set-key (kbd "g") 'sort-all-org-entries)))
```

**Following code also works, but is susceptible to errors as detailed in comments.**

`switch-to-buffer` allows selection of a buffer.  However, intended use is not for temporary functions.

```
(defun sort-all-org-entries ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer "foo.org") ## active buffer to execute function
  (let ((fun #'(lambda nil
                 (condition-case nil
                     (org-sort-entries nil ?d)
                   (user-error t)))))
    (org-map-entries fun))
   (switch-to-buffer())  ## returns to previous buffer (agenda)
   (org-agenda-redo())) ## refreshes agenda to reflect function effect
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 
    (lambda()
        (local-set-key (kbd "g") 'sort-all-org-entries)))
```

Comment: `switch-to-buffer` is not the way to do that  - see its doc string with `C-h f switch-to-buffer` which says: `WARNING: This is NOT the way to work on another buffer temporarily within a Lisp program!  Use ‘set-buffer’ instead.  That avoids
messing with the window-buffer correspondences.`. I advocated for `with-current-buffer` in my answer to your original question.

Comment: You still have the  problem I mentioned in my comment to your question: switching to the buffer and running the sorting code depends on where in the buffer you were before switching to the agenda and pressing `g`. If `point` was at the beginning, your function would behave as you expect, but if `point` was anywhere else, that's where your function would be applied after the `switch-to-buffer` producing unpredictable and unexpected results.

Comment: I misunderstood the use of 'with-current-buffer'.  It's use should be more elegant as the buffer work is designed to be temporary.  However replacement of `(switch-to-buffer "foo.org")` with `(with-current-buffer "foo.org")` does not work.  I am currently troubleshooting the correct use of `with-current-buffer`.

Comment: My second comment above does not  apply in this case (as you pointed out in your last comment under the question) because you are calling `org-map-entries` without a matcher. That makes it apply the function to every headline in the buffer. My comment would apply if you limited the matcher so that it would only match e.g the current subtree. In that case, the position is important.

Comment: The usage of `with-current-buffer`  (check with `C-h f with-current-buffer`) is `(with-current-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME &rest BODY)` where the `BODY` is the lisp code that you want to execute in the context of that buffer (in your case, the `(let ..)` form that defines the auxiliary function and calls `org-map-entry` with it).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Answer updated with new form